# Whole object as 'geo_point'

Tags: elasticsearch

I've declared a property of a document as 'Nested'. 'Locations' in this case. Is it possible for this object to be of 'geo_point' data type and have other information such as 'id'.

Something like this:

```
"user": {
    "locations": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "location": "40, 50"
        }
    ]
}
```

And is it possible to change the name of 'location'? I would like 'number_latitude' and 'number_longitude', but I need it to be a 'geo_point'.

Comment: extend geo_point into your own data type?

Comment: Exactly what I need

Comment: Is geo_point a mapping index?

Comment: Yes. It is a mapping index

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the mapping

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/auuser1/user1/_mapping' -d '{
"user": {
    "locations": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "location": "40, 50"

        }
    "locations_ext": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "location": "40, 50"
            "number_latitude": "40.00"
            "number_longitude": "-50.00"
        }
    ]
}
}'
```

[Extend Mapping](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/extend-mapping/9431)